# Reading buffer C/C++

Tags: c++, c, buffer

There is a function, I want to call

```
(void) get_bytes (void * ptr, int length)
```

function takes two arguments
the first is buffer (by that argument data will be recieved)
second length of the data that I want to read.

The task is to reading 10 bytes using this function, and print buffer on the screen (in the form of hexadecimal).

I tried this way

```
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
get_bytes (buffer, sizeof(buffer));
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%s", buffer[i]);
}
```

but I get exception of execution bad access on printf line,
Please provide a right way of passing buffer to this function

Comment: Try `%c` instead of `%s` Otherwise I think you are actually trying to write a non-null terminated string.

Comment: Your use of `sizeof` is incorrect. It will return the size of the `buffer` variable not the number of bytes or elements the array it points to holds.

Comment: I recommend using a buffer length variable. Maybe like `size_t buffer_len = sizeof(char)*10;` then it is `malloc(buffer_len)` and `get_bytes(buffer, buffer_len)`, etc.

Comment: @ZanLynx, after that how can I print the hexadecimal value of that 10 bytes?

Comment: @NarekSafaryan: Why ask me when Dietmar answered that question below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably meant to write

```
printf("%02x", (unsigned char)buffer[i]);
```

As is you are passing characters as addresses for strings which won't quite work.

Comment: @NarekSafaryan: I can - but I won't! You pretty much got the entire solution to the problem you described (there is another probelm with the buffer size you haven't encountered, yet, though) and it isn't the purpose of Stackoverflow to do your homework: I don't need any exercises anymore!

Comment: :D It's not a homework, it's from a real project for iOS to read bytes from advertised characteristics. But +1

Answer (score 1):

`get_bytes (buffer, sizeof(buffer));` isn't right... instead of `sizeof(buffer)` which returns the size of your char pointer, you want the size of what it's pointing to, `10` in this case.